# Can't constraint max width of Card inside ListView (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

My card is taking the whole screen width, while being inside of a `SizedBox` of width 50 (much smaller than the screen). What's going on? Here's my code:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
    children: const [
      SizedBox(
        width: 50,
        child: Card(
        child: Row(
          children: [
          Text('test'),
        ]),
        ),
      ),
    ]
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the child of `ListView` with `UnconstrainedBox` Widget.

From Official Docs: `UnconstrainedBox` imposes no constraints on its child, allowing it to render at its "natural" size. [Link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UnconstrainedBox-class.html)

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
    children: const [
      UnconstrainedBox(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 50,
          child: Card(
          child: Row(
            children: [
            Text('test'),
          ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Listview widget completely controls their children width and height, you can solve this issue using UnconstrainedBox widget before your widget

```
 Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          body: ListView(children: [
            UnconstrainedBox(
              child: Card(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Row(children: [
                    Text('test'),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ])),
```

there are two more solutions 1- using row 2- use stack before your widget , you can check this [link](https://medium.com/@mustafatahirhussein/the-containers-width-does-not-reflect-inside-a-listview-in-flutter-fixed-64cc2e73e287) for more information.